# How to write multiple HTML divs in a JS function

Tags: javascript, html

So I wanna print an object to my page and I have no idea how to write the code in JS so that on my page it prints multiple divs for each object.

What I wanna do is insert this

```
<div class="cv-block">
        <div id="parent_div_1">
            obiect.firstn
            obiect.lastn
        </div>

        <div id="parent_div_2">
            obiect.date
        </div>

        obiect.message

    </div>
```

into this java script function

```
function afisare (lista) {
var randuri = "";
lista.forEach(function (obiect) {

    randuri += ;
});
$("#obiect").html(randuri);}
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Who is calling `afisare` function? What is the content of `lista` and where is dom with id `obiect`?

Comment: `function cereLista(cautaText) {
    $.ajax("f?action=list", {
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            search: cautaText
        }
    }).done(function (lista) {
        console.info("a venit lista", lista);
        afisare(lista.tasks);
    });
}` is the function that requests the list.

Comment: I have another div in my .jsp page with `id="obiect"` and in `lista` I have an ArrayList if that's what you're talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way to do this is using template literal which is supported by ES6.
if you want to use it  in older browser you should use babel.

```html
$("#obiect").html(`<div class="cv-block">
        <div id="parent_div_1">
            ${obiect.firstn}
            ${obiect.lastn}
        </div>

        <div id="parent_div_2">
            ${obiect.date}
        </div>

        ${obiect.message}

    </div>`)
```

also there is ES5 code for it.

```html
$("#object").html("<div class=\"cv-block\">\n        <div id=\"parent_div_1\">\n            obiect.firstn\n            obiect.lastn\n        </div>\n\n        <div id=\"parent_div_2\">\n            obiect.date\n        </div>\n\n        obiect.message\n\n    </div>");
```

Comment: actually this works the best for me. Sorry if I asked wrong and it was hard to understand my question. I don't know JS very well, thank you so much for your help and time. Have a good one.